# Multiselect field required not working SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have created one Multiselect Field in SugarCRM using the Studio.
and I have checked the Required Field.
After that I have creating a case that time Without selecting the any checkbox the form should be submited.
that Required doesn't work for only Multiselect datatype field.
Please give me suggestion for the how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please specify your sugar version! If in doubt check the file https://your-sugar-site/sugar_version.json :)

Comment: {
 "sugar_version": "6.5.18",
 "sugar_db_version": "6.5.18",
 "sugar_flavor": "CE",
 "sugar_build": "1110",
 "sugar_timestamp": "2014-09-23 12:53pm"
}